# Уроки по JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет, с базовыми знаниями JS можно научиться хорошо работать с JQuery? прошу посоветовать хорошую литературу

Comment: Советую проштудировать: http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: Чтобы хорошо работать с jQuery, понадобятся еще базовые знания PHP или другого серверного языка. Это чтобы понять, как работает AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Онлайн курсы от jquery.com (анонсированы буквально пару недель назад):
http://try.jquery.com/

Курсы от таких популярных на сегодняшний день codeschool:
[http://www.codeschool.com/](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery)

Comment: о, точняк, про такие штуки забыл ) еще codecademy.com есть

Answer (score 4):

С базовыми знаниями научиться можно. Основные понятия jQuery Вы сможете найти здесь [Клик](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38208/)

Comment: вы дали ссылку на тот же учебник Антона, только выложенный не на его сайте, а на другом ресурсе :)

Comment: Я наверняка писал Вам ответ, когда Антон уже ответил :)

Comment: Антон не отвечал, он написал этот учебник :)

кстати, рекомендую его блог к ознакомлению не только начинающим

Comment: кстати, в комментариях к тому репосту, что вы скинули, есть ссылка на еще один очень интересный материал:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/31239/

Comment: @actionless, Шевчук перевел статьи, а не писал их - это раз. Во-вторых, читать их надо аккуратно, т.к. там описываются некоторые методы, которые на сегодняшний день или устарели, или вообще не используются.

Comment: про первое не знал.
по поводу второго - для ознакомления, мне кажется, сойдет. еще второй перевод, комментом выше, вроде неплохо написан, но там объём по-меньше.
а больше я ничего особо на русском и не встречал, честно говоря.

Comment: @actionless, я бы посоветовал читать и тренироваться на этих статьях, подключив свежую версию библиотеки и [jQuery Migrate](http://jquery.com/download/). В этом случае, можно обучаясь, отслеживать устаревшие методы.

Answer (score 2):

да, конечно.

http://anton.shevchuk.name/jquery/
http://anton.shevchuk.name/book/code/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть видеоуроки по встраиванию различных плагинов и т.д. на сайт, если тебя интересуют просто статьи, то они там тоже есть. [link text](http://originalip.ru) Ещё мне очень нравится сайт jquery-docs.ru, очень здоровский.